# How to Insert an object in a list at custom index

Tags: c#, .net, list, object

I have an empty list defined to hold 120 values, I want to insert an element at index(45), even though the list is currently empty. Is this possible?

```
public List<Ticket> Tickets = new List<Ticket>(120);

Tickets.Insert(45,ticket); // Here I am getting the ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to insert an item at a specific "index" in an empty list? Why not a dictionary? It would be easier to solve the original problem than try to change the behaviour of List<T>

Comment: Will it a better solution to use other datastructure like `Dictionary<int, Ticket>` or custom container?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You set the initial internal capacity of the list to 120. The list is still empty.

`List<T>` can hold any number of items. Internally, it uses an array to store them. If the array gets full, the list will allocate a new, larger one. If you know the number of items in advance, you can set the size of the internal array when you construct the list. This way you can avoid unnecessary memory allocation.

You could use an array:

```
Ticket[] tickets = new Ticket[120];
tickets[45] = ticket
```

or a `Dictionary<int, Ticket>`

```
Dictionary<int, Ticket> tickets = new Dictionary<int, Ticket>();
tickets.Add(45, ticket);
```

or create a `List<Ticket>` holding 120 nulls:

```
List<Ticket> tickets = Enumerable.Repeat(default(Ticket), 120).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

`120` is defined as the [capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dw8e0z9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the list - not the really existing elements. So in this case your list contains 0 elements at insert.

When you try to insert a element at position 45 into a empty list - a ArgumentOutOfRangeException makes sense

Comment: Yes I am very aware of that, so my question is is there any way of doing this what I want? To add an element to the specified index?

Comment: How can you add them without having any element in the list before hand? does not make sense.@NaughtyNinja

Comment: Doing what? There is no index position 45 when you insert the first item. This would only exist if you actually filled the list with 120 "default" tickets. You are trying to tread a variable-length collection as if it were an array or a dictionary (hint)

Comment: @NaughtyNinja use an array instead

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary also

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int,Ticket>();
dic[45] = ticket;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should populate list with something, because this ctor of List doesnt populate it.

```
public List<Ticket> Tickets =  new List<Ticket>(Enumerable.Repeat (new Ticket(), 120));

Tickets[45] = ticket;
```

Comment: I have a feeling an array might be more sensible as a data structure for this usecase.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor that takes an `int` is there to define the initial capacity, not the initial number of elements.

When you try to add an element to the list the following code is run:

```
private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
  if (this._items.Length >= min)
    return;
  int num = this._items.Length == 0 ? 4 : this._items.Length * 2;
  if ((uint) num > 2146435071U)
    num = 2146435071;
  if (num < min)
    num = min;
  this.Capacity = num;
}
```

The key thing is that it tries to double the capacity each time it runs out of space. This results is an array copy for each doubling. To avoid the computation cost of doubling when you know the size of the list to begin with you set the initial capacity.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create the list through the array, which default initializes all elements:

```
List<Ticket> tickets = new Ticket[120].ToList();
tickets[45] = ticket;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dictionary<int, Ticket> Tickets = new Dictionary<int,Ticket>;
    Tickets.Add(45, tickets);
```

Does it need to be a list and does order matter? If not why not use a dictionary or a another key/value object?